# duplicated field in select with using criteria query jpa 2.0

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a problem with the description CriteriaQuery. My code...

```
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(String.class);
...
Expression selection = criteriaBuilder.function("to_char", String.class, pathField);

criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select(selection)
                             .distinct(true)
                             .orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(selection));

...
return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

I get a query in the logs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT to_char(t0.FIELD), to_char(t0.FIELD) 
FROM TABLE t0 
ORDER BY to_char(t0.FIELD) ASC
```

Why is my field duplicated? How can I solve this problem? Thank

Comment: What are you using? Hibernate or EclipseLink?

Comment: or a different JPA provider ?

Comment: I am using EclipseLink